# xml appenchild with different values

Tags: c#, xml, appendchild, xmlnode

I am trying to write to xml programatically.

In attempting to achieve something like this:-

```
<module>
  <moduleCode>EIGA501</moduleCode>
  <moduleTitle>Introduction to 3D Graphics</moduleTitle>
  <credits>15</credits>
  <semester>1</semester>
  <assessmentDetails>
    <assessment>
      <assessmentName>Coursework1</assessmentName>
      <assessmentType>Coursework</assessmentType>
      <assessmentWeighting>25</assessmentWeighting>
    </assessment>
    <assessment>
      <assessmentName>Coursework2</assessmentName>
      <assessmentType>Coursework</assessmentType>
      <assessmentWeighting>35</assessmentWeighting>
    </assessment>
    <assessment>
      <assessmentName>Exam</assessmentName>
      <assessmentType>Exam</assessmentType>
      <assessmentWeighting>40</assessmentWeighting>
    </assessment>
  </assessmentDetails>
  <school>ECS</school>
</module>
```

Where notice the assesmentDetails node is beautifully formatted, I am instead achieving this:

```
<module>
  <moduleCode>someCode</moduleCode>
  <moduleTitle>someCourseTitle</moduleTitle>
  <credits>someCredits</credits>
  <semester>2</semester>
  <assesmentDetails>
    <assesment>
    </assesment>
    <assesment>
    </assesment>
    <assesment>
      <assesmentName>AssesmentName1AssesmentName2</assesmentName>
      <assesmentType>AssesmentType1AssesmentType2</assesmentType>
      <assesmentWeighting>12</assesmentWeighting>
    </assesment>
  </assesmentDetails>
  <school>ECS</school>
</module>
```

I am succesfully building the rest of the xml fine as you can see, I am using a for loop to attempt to build the assesment section 'dynamically'. As shown:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textboxComputer.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlElement newAssesment = document.CreateElement("assesment");
                newAssesmentD.AppendChild(newAssesment);

                TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)textboxComputer[i];
                TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)textboxP[i];
                TextBox tb3 = (TextBox)textboxPercent[i];

                XmlText assesmentN = document.CreateTextNode(tb1.Text);
                XmlText assesmentT = document.CreateTextNode(tb2.Text);
                XmlText assesmentW = document.CreateTextNode(tb3.Text);

                newAssesment.AppendChild(newAssesmentN);
                newAssesment.AppendChild(newAssesmentT);
                newAssesment.AppendChild(newAssesmentW);

                newAssesmentN.AppendChild(assesmentN);
                newAssesmentT.AppendChild(assesmentT);
                newAssesmentW.AppendChild(assesmentW); 
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this homework?  There are now two different users with similar xml.

Comment: With all due respect, whether it is 'homework' or not is irrelevant, this is a project that I am working on and have come to a snag.

Comment: homework should be tagged as such, is all.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LinqToXml, you can add nodes in this fashion.

```
XElement a = new XElement("assesment");
a.Add(new XElement("assesmentName", "name text");
```

You can find the `assesmentDetails` node like this,

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
XElement module = root.Elements("module")
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Element("moduleCode").Value == "code");
if(null != module)
{
    XElement assesmentDetails = module.Element("assesmentDetails");
    assesmentDetails.Add(a); // <-- Add your new assesment
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you suggest LinqToXml as the only viable solution? I have very little experience with Linq and dread the risk of turning my work into an error-box!

Comment: LinqToXml is easier to use than XmlElement.  LinqToXml came out with .Net 3.5 and XmlElement is .Net 1.0

Comment: Lambda's `=>`  are the most difficult concept of Linq.  `(a, b) => a + b` is the same as `int f(int a, int b){ return a + b; }`.  The compiler handles the type of the variables for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Looking into LinqToXml tutorials and MSDN docs now!